# Question on Black-Scholes Equation

Tags: brownian-motion, finance

Consider a call option having a strike price $K$ and exercise time $t$; let $r$ be the nominal rate, $\sigma$ volatility and $S_0$ the underlying asset at $t = 0$. How to show that $C(t, S_0,K,\sigma,r) \geq (S_0 - e^{-rt}K)^{+}$ and $C(t, S_0,K,\sigma,r)\leq S_0$? 
I tried to use

$C(t, S_0,K,\sigma,r) = e^{-rt}\mathbb{E}[(S(t)-K)^{+}]$

But I could not get rid of the mean.

Comment: what do you mean by $C$?

Comment: isn't $S_0$ usually the price of the underlying asset at t=0, not the price of the call at t=0?

Comment: @oks, edited, $C = C(t, S_0,K,\sigma,r)$ is the non-arbitrary cost of the call.

Comment: Can you use a no-arbitrage argument?  C + S pays out max(K,S)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake $C + Ke^{-rt}$ pays out max(K,S)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C + Ke^{-rt}$ pays out at least $S(t)$, since $C + Ke^{-rt}$ provides enough to buy the stock and have and sell it for $S(t)$, so by no-arbitrage
$C + Ke^{-rt} \ge S_0$.

If $C > S_0$ then you could make arbitrage profits of $C - S_0$ by selling the option and buying the stock.  If the option is exercised you get the lower of $K$ and S(t), so overall you get a risk free gain of $C - S_0$ (immediately) + min(K,S) on expiry.  By no-arbitrage, $C \le S_0$.